# How do i use .htaccess to restrict access from all but allow access from one?

Tags: html, apache, validation, .htaccess

I know the title seems pretty confusing but here's the question.
How do i use .htaccess or any alternatives to restrict access to thankyou.html?

In this case, no one will be able to go to http://www.mydomain.com/thankyou.html directly or through referrals.

I'm trying to achieve something where users can only get to http://www.mydomain.com/thankyou.html when they submitted a form with successful validation.

I'm not using PHP, I'm basically using html to send the response to google docs.

Comment: I don't think this is an htaccess question. I'd look into cookies, sessions or something similar. Using just HTML won't get you there from my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I believe youd have to use a file directive in your .htaccess and chuck the .htaccess in the same directory as the file.

```
<Files thankyou.html>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Protected Access"
    AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd
    Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Source: [Here](http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2007/01/09/password-protecting-single-file-htaccess.html)

Comment: Did you understand the question properly? They want to block sites out by referrer, not by password.

Comment: yes I pasted an example of how to use a file directive... im not telling the user to use this exactly.